# output while reading keyboard input

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal

I'm trying to write a script that will `ssh` into a box, start a processes that needs to be monitored (by a human) for success or failure then move onto the next box and repeat.

I've been trying to use tail or `tail -f` on the log that the process writes to, but I've yet to find a way to get the script to read keyboard input while the `tail -f` is running.

Ideally I'd like to `tail -f` the log until I see the process was successful, press a key and have the script move on, OR press another key if the startup errors out and exit the script.

Is this possible?

So far I've only come up with:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    kb=""
    until [ "$kb" == "n" ]; do
    tail /var/log/java-app.log
    read -t 1 kb
    done
```

It mostly works, but it's klunky.  I'm starting up java apps and there are pauses so occasionally the same 10 lines are repeated and I have to hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to have the <kbd>n</kbd> acknowledged.
I'd really like to use `tail -f` and still read (ideally 2) different vars from the keyboard.  Is this possible?

{edit}
I'm actually thinking that

```
tail -f /var/log/java-app.log | tee > ( grep -q "YADA YADA" )
```

Is my best bet.  I can just <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> if I find errors.

Comment: You don't seem to be observing that your program might already have exited while watching the log. In a similar situation (I had to scan the output from the process as well as a log) I ended up writing a program that looped while 1) scanning for keyboard input 2) write out output and log to stdout for visual check (suppressing non-interesting lines). This was extended over time with 3) automated scanning for patterns in log and output. I am not sure if you can do that as easily with shell programming.

Comment: Well, that's the thing.  I need those non-interesting lines to check for errors.  Basically I'm starting up several JVMs across about 10 servers.  I need to see all of the output.  When I see it's "started successfully" I want it to continue onto the next JVM or server.  If I see errors I want the whole script to die.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but e.g. you repeat the tail and there might be to many lines passed already, so you miss things, or not enough, so you see things multiple times. In my program I record the size of the log, and display additional bytes/lines, after checking for keyboard events.

Comment: Agreed.  Which is why I am leaning toward        tail -f /var/log/java-app.log | tee >( grep -q "YADA YADA" )  instead.  Grep will exit when it finds the match I am looking for and the script moves to the next step.  If I see it failing I can ctrl+C.

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Starting tail in the background..." 
tail -f input &
pid=$!
trap "kill $pid" EXIT
while true; do
        read kb
        test n = "$kb" && break
done
```

Comment: this might work if I put in two [test] instances for kb.  I need one to continue, and one to kill the whole script.